# How to force content of diagnostics.wadcfg to be reflected in wad-control-container

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I've setup a diagnostics.wadcfg with lots of performance counter **(90+)**.However, it's not been reflected on wad-control-container blob. I also made sure that this file is located under **BIN** folder.

My webrole has code snippet below OnStart():

```
   // Get the diagnostic monitor for the specified role instance.
RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = 
         new RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager(myStorageAccount, 
                                           "28281fc7754b44faa9ccf4911983edf1",
                                           "MyWebRole",
                                           "deployment(1).MyAzureProject.WebRole1.0");

// Get the current diagnostic monitor for the role.
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration currentConfiguration = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

// Use 30 seconds for the performance counter sample rate.
TimeSpan perfSampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);

// Add a performance counter for processor time to the current configuration.
currentConfiguration.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(new PerformanceCounterConfiguration()
{
      CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
      SampleRate = perfSampleRate
});

// Apply the modified configuration to the diagnostic monitor for the role instance.
roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(currentConfiguration);
```

Is it possible that OnStart() logic takes precedence and overwrites my content on diagnostics.wadcfg?

My diagnostics.wadcfg file below:

```
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration"
  configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M"
  overallQuotaInMB="8192">

  <PerformanceCounters bufferQuotaInMB="100" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">

    <!-- 1. AZURE_ASP_NET -->
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Application Restarts" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Applications Running" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Request Execution Time" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Current" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Disconnected" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Request Wait Time" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\State Server Sessions Abandoned" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\State Server Sessions Active" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\State Server Sessions Timed Out" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\State Server Sessions Total" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Worker Processes Running" sampleRate="PT30S" />
    <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Worker Process Restarts" sampleRate="PT30S" />

  </PerformanceCounters>

</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a file already in the wad-control-container in BLOB storage for that deployment, Role and instance it will take precedence.  That way if you are modifying that file externally to the system then a recycle of the role won't lose the settings.

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh771389.aspx):

> "The .wadcfg file is ignored if there is already an XML configuration
>   in the wad-control-container blob storage container."

The order of precedence can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205146.aspx.

My understanding is that by including the wadcfg file in your solution the diagnostics subsystem picks that file up and uses it as the defaults.  A copy of that file is then placed in the wad-control-container if there isn't already a file there.

Another thing to note is that you shared the code to configure that performance counter, but do you then pass that configuration on?  Can you post more of the OnStart for any code line that deals with your configuring of the diagnostics?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've updated the code. if i deleted xml from wad-control-container, and my wadcfg file contains only stuff for performance. Does it mean my final config will only contain performance counter only or other IIS, Eventlog etc. Bit confusing really

Comment: My understanding is that the wadcfg becomes what is configured, so if it isn't in there it doesn't get included.  I've not tested that but from the statement that it replaces the defaults I would believe that is what happens.

Comment: And I verified with someone on the product team, the precedence indicated in the document I pointed to hasn't changed. They are in the process of updating the documentation to add additional information.